# how to expand a divider to the whole window width in flutter app?

Tags: flutter

i have a list separated with dividers but the said dividers don't take the window's width. here is my code :

```
   Divider(
      color: Colors.black,
      height: 20,
      thickness: 0.5,
      indent: 20,
      endIndent: 0,
    ),
```

and the picture of the result 
[image]

Comment: probably your divider is inside a widget that contains a padding.

Comment: Maybe you should share a screenshot

Comment: Can you please give here reference where you see divider don't take full width?

Comment: here is the link where i took the code: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Divider-class.html

Comment: May be the widget wrapping divider have padding. You can check using flutter inspector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the indent property to 0;

```
Divider(
      color: Colors.black,
      height: 20,
      thickness: 0.5,
      indent: 0,
      endIndent: 0,
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Even you can use Containers like this

```
Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        width: 450,
        height: 1,
        color: Colors.black
    ),
```